# Добавляет ли метод First или Last в классе List в сам список?

Tags: c#, linq

```
Point first = new Point(16, 23, '*'); // обычный класс с координатами и символом
Point second= new Point(17, 23, '*');
Point third = new Point(18, 23, '*');
List<Point> listOfPoints = new List<Point>();

listOfPoints.Add(first);
listOfPoints.Add(second);
listOfPoints.Add(third);

Point asd = listOfPoints.First(); // скопировал параметры первой точки или заменил ее?

if (listOfPoints.Remove(asd) == true) // как он ремувает, если точка не была добавлена в список?
{

    Console.WriteLine("Либо он ремувнул точку first, так как взял лишь данные с точки asd");
    foreach(Point i in listOfPoints)
    {
        i.Draw(); // выводятся всего две точки
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("В элс не заходит при таких условиях");
}
```

Comment: добавь определение Point

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Point asd = listOfPoints.First(); // скопировал параметры первой точки
> или заменил ее?
> ```

[`Enumerable.First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) - берет первый `first` элемент из коллекции, если коллекция пуста - падает эксепшн.

> ```
> if (listOfPoints.Remove(asd) == true) // как он ремувает, если точка не была добавлена в список?
> ```

Удаляет этот первый элемент.

> ```
> foreach(Point i in listOfPoints)
> {
>     i.Draw(); // выводятся всего две точки
> }
> ```

Выводятся оставшиеся точки `second` и `third`.